Problema con el primer render del layout de NextJs
Estoy creando una navbar para incluirla en el layout.tsx de mi proyecto Next.js. Sin embargo, cuando inicio la página, aparece un error relacionado con "chunks". Esta navbar está hecha utilizando shadcnui , por lo que he añadido "use client" al principio del archivo.
El problema es que si incluyo la navbar en layout.tsx, aparece el error de chunks. En cambio, si uso el componente de la navbar directamente en page.tsx, el problema no se presenta y funciona correctamente.
¿Qué puede estar causando este error de chunks al usar la navbar en layout.tsx, y cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Version de nextjs:14.2.4
Layout.tsx:

import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

import Footer from "@/components/Footer";
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar"
import NavBarDesktop from "@/components/NavBarDesktop";
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <NavBar />
        <main>
          <NavBarDesktop />
          {children}
        </main>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


NavBarComponent:
"use client";
import HamburgerMenu from "@/icons/HamburgerMenu";
import SheetMenu from "./NavBarContent";
import {
  Sheet,
  SheetContent,
  SheetHeader,
  SheetTitle,
  SheetTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/sheet";
import { ScrollArea } from "./ui/scroll-area";
import Link from "next/link";

function NavBarMobile() {
  return (
    <Sheet>
      <SheetTrigger className="lg:hidden">
        <HamburgerMenu className="text-red-600" />
      </SheetTrigger>
      <SheetContent side={"left"} className="bg-slate-800">
        <ScrollArea className="h-full w-full  ">
        <Link href={"/"} className="w-full">
          <SheetHeader className="flex flex-row justify-center text-lg gap-4  items-center h-10">
            <SheetTitle className="text-red-600">Vaskins</SheetTitle>
            <picture className='max-w-8'>
                    <img src="/ValorantLogo.png" alt="valorant logo" />
                </picture>
          </SheetHeader>
          </Link>
          <ul className={`mt-2 mb-2 text-gray-400 flex  flex-col`}>
            <SheetMenu />
          </ul>
        </ScrollArea>
      </SheetContent>
    </Sheet>
  );
}

export default NavBarMobile;



Error completo de la consola:

1-layout.js:412 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

2-react-server-dom-web…development.js:1196 Uncaught 
ChunkLoadError
    at __webpack_require__.f.j (webpack.js?v=1720536911850:854:29)
    at webpack.js?v=1720536911850:157:40
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.e (webpack.js?v=1720536911850:156:67)
    at fn.e (webpack.js?v=1720536911850:393:50)
    at loadChunk (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:244:30)
    at preloadModule (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:170:22)
    at resolveModule (react-server-dom-web…elopment.js:1813:17)
    at processFullRow (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:1902:9)
    at processBinaryChunk (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:2072:7)
    at progress (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:2153:5)
readChunk   @   react-server-dom-web…development.js:1196
mountLazyComponent  @   react-dom.development.js:16750
beginWork$1 @   react-dom.development.js:18464
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:20565
invokeGuardedCallbackImpl   @   react-dom.development.js:20614
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:20689
beginWork   @   react-dom.development.js:26949
performUnitOfWork   @   react-dom.development.js:25748
workLoopSync    @   react-dom.development.js:25464
renderRootSync  @   react-dom.development.js:25419
performSyncWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:24887
flushSyncWorkAcrossRoots_impl   @   react-dom.development.js:7758
flushSyncWorkOnAllRoots @   react-dom.development.js:7718
processRootScheduleInMicrotask  @   react-dom.development.js:7863
eval    @   react-dom.development.js:8034

3-Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>.

4-ChunkLoadError
    at __webpack_require__.f.j (webpack.js?v=1720536911850:854:29)
    at webpack.js?v=1720536911850:157:40
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.e (webpack.js?v=1720536911850:156:67)
    at fn.e (webpack.js?v=1720536911850:393:50)
    at loadChunk (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:244:30)
    at preloadModule (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:170:22)
    at resolveModule (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1813:17)
    at processFullRow (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1902:9)
    at processBinaryChunk (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:2072:7)
    at progress (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:2153:5)

5-Uncaught ChunkLoadError
    at __webpack_require__.f.j (webpack.js?v=1720536911850:854:29)
    at webpack.js?v=1720536911850:157:40
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.e (webpack.js?v=1720536911850:156:67)
    at fn.e (webpack.js?v=1720536911850:393:50)
    at loadChunk (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:244:30)
    at preloadModule (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:170:22)
    at resolveModule (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1813:17)
    at processFullRow (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1902:9)
    at processBinaryChunk (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:2072:7)
    at progress (react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:2153:5)


6-not-found-boundary.js:37 Uncaught 
ChunkLoadError
    at __webpack_require__.f.j (webpack.js?v=1720536911850:854:29)
    at webpack.js?v=1720536911850:157:40
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.e (webpack.js?v=1720536911850:156:67)
    at fn.e (webpack.js?v=1720536911850:393:50)
    at loadChunk (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:244:30)
    at preloadModule (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:170:22)
    at resolveModule (react-server-dom-web…elopment.js:1813:17)
    at processFullRow (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:1902:9)
    at processBinaryChunk (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:2072:7)
    at progress (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:2153:5)



7-The above error occurred in the <NotFoundErrorBoundary> component:

    at Lazy
    at body
    at html
    at RootLayout (Server)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:74:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:82:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:76:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:11)
    at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:33:11)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/ReactDevOverlay.js:87:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/hot-reloader-client.js:321:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:207:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:113:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:160:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:585:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:112:27)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:117:11)

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ReactDevOverlay.



8-Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
    at updateHostRoot (react-dom.development.js:16571:57)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:18486:14)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:26927:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:25748:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:25464:5)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:25419:7)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:24597:20)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24899:20)
    at flushSyncWorkAcrossRoots_impl (react-dom.development.js:7758:13)
    at flushSyncWorkOnAllRoots (react-dom.development.js:7718:3)
    at processRootScheduleInMicrotask (react-dom.development.js:7863:3)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js:8034:7)
updateHostRoot @ react-dom.development.js:16571
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:18486
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:26927
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:25748
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:25464
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:25419
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:24597
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:24899
flushSyncWorkAcrossRoots_impl @ react-dom.development.js:7758
flushSyncWorkOnAllRoots @ react-dom.development.js:7718
processRootScheduleInMicrotask @ react-dom.development.js:7863
eval @ react-dom.development.js:8034
Show 12 more frames
Show less



¿Es NavBarDesktop o NavBarMobile? Intenta exportar el componente como dynamic, avisanos del resultado...

Ya los agregue como dynamic, pero no funciona, creo que migrare el proyecto a vitejs

Es un error de hydration, sugiero que uses el dynamic import pero esta vez en los componentes que estas importando para NavBarDesktop o NavBarMobile x ejemplo ScrollArea etc..., esto no resuelve el error, es solo una especie de workaround, pero te ayuda a identificar cual componente esta causando el problema de hydration.
